# Displaying CSV data into graphs and tables

Tags: jquery, csv, graph, qgraphicsview

I would like to ask how would you go about displaying ton of CSV data. We need to show various counts, averages and so on. I think this should be doable in some kind of tools?

Comment: flot is a pretty nice jQuery-plugin: http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is [jquerycvstotable](https://code.google.com/p/jquerycsvtotable/)

```
<div id="CSVTable"></div>

<script>
$(function() {
  $('#CSVTable').CSVToTable('test.csv');
});
</script>
```

Edit: I just found another one that may be more promising if you're trying to load them into a graphical chart. It's called [jquery-csv](https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [jquery-csv](https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv)

[The Basic Usage demo](http://evanplaice.github.io/jquery-csv/examples/basic-usage.html)

Shows how to load CSV data into an HTML table

[The Flot demo](http://evanplaice.github.io/jquery-csv/examples/flot.html)

Shows how to load data into a Flot chart

[The Google Visualization demo](http://evanplaice.github.io/jquery-csv/examples/google-visualization.html)

shows how to use it with the Google Vizualization API

*Disclaimer: I'm the author of jquery-csv*